# Power BI Create Custom Visual Tutorial: Add formatting options to the Circle Card visual

Tags: typescript, powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals

[Power BI Create Custom Visual Tutorial: Add formatting options to the Circle Card visual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/visuals/custom-visual-develop-tutorial-format-options)

From step 8 I have added the code to my VS Code & got 2 error message

1. import VisualSettings
   Module '"./settings"' has no exported member 'VisualSettings'.
2. Cannot find name 'VisualSettingsModel'. Did you mean 'VisualSettings'?

[error details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6V26R.png)
pls suggests the changes to fix the code.

I tried changing VisualSettings -> VisualSettingsModel & cleared error but not getting output in the App.powerbi.com
I can only see a blank visual in the output. Values are not displayed only title is appearing

Answer (score 1):

the settings.ts file should contain a class called `VisualSettings`.  Please check that the contents of the settings file looks like this:

```
"use strict";

import { dataViewObjectsParser } from "powerbi-visuals-utils-dataviewutils";
import DataViewObjectsParser = dataViewObjectsParser.DataViewObjectsParser;

export class CircleSettings{
  public circleColor: string = "white";
  public circleThickness: number = 2;
}

export class VisualSettings extends DataViewObjectsParser{
  public circle: CircleSettings = new CircleSettings();
}
```

You can check this against the github repo: https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-visuals-circlecard/blob/master/src/settings.ts